# Expo Go suddenly not working unless using it --tunnel

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code, expo, expo-go

I was developing an app with Expo and Expo Go. They all worked fine, yet suddenly when I made a change in style.js file (whatever minor update), Expo Go app started to load the app forever from both Android emulator (on my Windows laptop) and my iPhone Expo Go app. However, somehow when I do `npm expo start --tunnel` (instead of `npm expo start`) it works fines from both iPhone and laptop. Do you happen to know what could be a possible root cause of this? (I'm using VSC terminal)